# Dockerfile, how should modify file into a pip package inside Docker

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

In my Dockerfile, I pip install a few python packages (using requirements). One of them needs a `credentials.json` file filled with login and password credentials to work(The json file is empty after pip installing it).

So in the Dockerfile, I am trying to paste credentials into the config.json file. I have tried multiple path to find it but I always have "Directory nonexistent" error message.

Is it possible to access package directories in the docker image ? If yes, what is the "good" path to access it ?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

WORKDIR /app

## Install Pip
RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get install -y python3 python3-dev curl && \
   curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py | python3

# pip install requirements
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# load env variables (including MY_LOGIN and MY_PASSWORD)
COPY .env ./.env
RUN . ./.env

# add credentials json into the python package
RUN echo "{'login': '$MY_LOGIN', 'password': '$MY_PASSWORD', 'url': 'https://url_test.com/vtest', 'login_url': 'https://auth.test.com/vtest/login'}" > ./package_name/folder/connector/credentials.json

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "other_package/main.py"]
```

PS: This is my first Dockerfile so if you have any other comment to improve it you are more than welcome :)

Comment: Can you add more information about which package are your using credentials.json for and if that package requires you to put the file in a specific location ?

Comment: Sorry it is a private package from my company. I do need to have this credentials.json file in package_name/folder/connector/

Comment: I'm assuming that you have your Dockerfile in revision control. I'd recommend *not* putting secrets into git. There are a number of different solutions in the secrets management space.

Comment: You are trying to write to `/app/package_name/folder/connector/credentials.json` which apparently doesn't exist.  Almost certainly because `pip` is not installing packages under `/app`, it is putting them in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` so I would try changing the file location to `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/package_name/folder/connector/credentials.json` -- but it's hard to tell here without the details.

Comment: I would like to point out that you can always run `RUN ls -l` inside your Dockerfile to see the directories.

Comment: @kthompso thanks, but still Directory nonexistent.
I also tried `../usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/package_name/folder/connector/credentials.json` or `usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/package_name/folder/connector/credentials.json`

Comment: @LuisCárcamo thanks, but this line does not output anything in my terminal

Comment: You need to find out where this package is being installed, it is almost 100% certainly under `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` so that leads me to believe that either the package is not being installed or you have the path to the `connector` folder wrong.  You could try removing the `RUN echo ...` line from your Dockerfile, build your image, and then look around the filesystem with `docker run -it <your-image-id> bash`.  It's very difficult to diagnose the exact issue if the package and its contents are hidden from us.  Good luck.